# mvn release:perform tries to put sources.jar twice to nexus

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

mvn release perform tries to put sources.jar twice to nexus.
Firstly it puts it with other artifacts (.war, javadoc.jar..).
Then it does bulk deploy and tries to put sources.jar again. Any ideas what is happening ?

```
[INFO] [INFO] Bulk deploying locally gathered artifacts from directory:
[INFO] [INFO]  * Bulk deploying locally gathered snapshot artifacts to URL
```

Comment: Can you put a full log ouput here..How have you configured maven-source-plugin?

Comment: just checked, it is not configured anywhere in the project. should i add one to parent pom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maven-deploy-plugin was conflicting with nexus-staging-maven-plugin. I had to put
`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
             <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
</plugin>`